# urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, urllib3

I am trying to open a website on chrome using Python Selenium chromedriver. Chrome browser is opening (with warnings) and the url is not opening.

Version details : Chrome : 68.0.3440.106 
                  selenium : 3.14.0
                  chromedriver : 2.20
                  python : 2.7

I am using below code :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Python27/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/")
print(driver.title)
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

I am getting below error:

```
C:\Users\sohil7777\PycharmProjects\temp.py\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/sohil7777/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sohil7777/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Python27/chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 318, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 375, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 72, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 150, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 322, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 377, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 1121, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 438, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 394, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
```

Am i missing something? Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.20*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.20*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.20/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v43-48**

- You are using *chrome=68.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.33* and the *Chrome Browser v65.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.41**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v67-69*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.41 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.