# Django StaticLiveServerTestCase sometimes ends with: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, django, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

In an Django application that I freshly created, where I changed it to use PostgreSQL and I created one app, I have the following test:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class TestWebBrowser(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.webdriver.implicitly_wait(10)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.webdriver.close()
        cls.webdriver.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def setUp(self):
        self.admin = User.objects.create_superuser(username="username", password="password",
                                                   email="example@example.com")

    def test_log_in(self):
        self.webdriver.get(f"{self.live_server_url}/admin")
        self.webdriver.find_element_by_id("id_username").send_keys("username")
        self.webdriver.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys("password")
        self.webdriver.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        self.webdriver.find_element_by_link_text("Users").click()
```

The test always runs, Chrome starts, does what the test say, but at the end, sometimes it throws this error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55283)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 139, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

All tests pass. I just get that to `STDERR`. Any ideas why? Am I missing some tearing-down?

If I change `tearDownClass` to:

```
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.webdriver.quit()
```

I get the same error with the same frequency (as far as I can observe, without having measured it).

I'm running:

```
Django==2.1.2
selenium==3.141.0
```

and

```
> chromedriver.exe --version
ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a)
```

and

```
Google Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

The full output of running the tests look like this:

```
Testing started at 15:33 ...
C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pycharm\django_test_manage.py" test foo.tests.TestImportCRMData C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\untitled
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49825)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\Temporary\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 139, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @DebanjanB: I don't think this is a duplicate question. The other one is about not managing to communicate with the chromedriver, while in my case that works. The error happens at the end.

Comment: That's all the stack trace I'm getting. It must be happening on a separate thread.

Comment: Can you help me to identify exactly at which line you are seeing the error?

Comment: It doesn't happen on any line of my code. My tests all pass, and I just get that to `STDERR` every now and then.

Comment: I'm guessing is something failing during tear down.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to communicate with the **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session as it was forcibly closed by the remote host.

---

Your main issue is the multiple calls in the form of **`webdriver.close()`** and **`webdriver.quit()`**

While automating through **Selenium** as per the best practices to terminate a connection you should always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully. Invoking `quit()` method `DELETE`s the current browsing session through sending **"quit"** command with **{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}** and finally sends the **GET** request on **/shutdown** `EndPoint`. Here is an example below :

```
1503397488598   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> DELETE /session/8e457516-3335-4d3b-9140-53fb52aa8b74 
1503397488607   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   -> 37:[0,4,"quit",{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}]
1503397488821   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /shutdown
```

So on invoking **`quit()`** method the `Web Browser` session and the `WebDriver` instance gets killed completely. Hence you don't have to incorporate any additional steps (invoking `close()`) which will be an overhead by the prevailing standards.

---

### Solution

First of all you remove the following line:

```
cls.webdriver.close()
```

The very next line:

```
cls.webdriver.quit()
```

Is bound to terminate the connection in the best possible way.

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling)

---

### Update A

As per the [liveservertestcase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) the `tearDownClass()` *@classmethod* isdefined as:

```
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.selenium.quit()
    super().tearDownClass()
```

As per [django/django/test/testcases.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b3b1d3d45fc066367f4fcacf0b06f72fcd00a9c6/django/test/testcases.py#L1367-L1371) this is called:

```
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls._tearDownClassInternal()
    cls._live_server_modified_settings.disable()
    super().tearDownClass()
```

---

### Update B

Though you mentioned about:

- Using **ChromeDriver 2.43.600210**
- Using **Google Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102**

As per release notes of [ChromeDriver v2.43](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt):

> Supports Chrome v69-71

- So they are compatible but possibly there are multiple installations of *Google Chrome* installed in your machine and the mismatched version of *Google Chrome* binary is invoked when the following line is executed:

  ```
  cls.webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
  ```

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can finda couple of relevant discussions in:

- [urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799251/urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-aborted-error10054-an-exist/51799372#51799372)

Comment: Having just `quit()` and no `close()` results in the same error. I tried all the permutations of these two methods and none worked without an error.

Comment: @pupeno I missed your step `super().tearDownClass()`. Is that necessary?

Comment: I added it because of the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase. This is the code that's being called: https://github.com/django/django/blob/b3b1d3d45fc066367f4fcacf0b06f72fcd00a9c6/django/test/testcases.py#L1367-L1371

Comment: As per the reference discussion you need to call `quit()` only once which gracefully clears up the webdriver and web browser. Any additional step will raise an exception.

Comment: I updated the question with this information. Just calling `quit()` throws the same error. Looking at the backtrace, I think the error is in django's server, not in selenium.

Comment: @pupeno Added an answer update. Let me know the result.