# RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without" http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Since Google denies access to API key of Google MyBusiness to all but established firms, I attempted to automate the process of changing my business information using selenium webdriver.

What works?

Logging in to Google Mybusiness by automating the login form.

*What doesnt work?*

After logging in, I need to open the small modal of editing working hours. I attempted to automate a click on the edit button, but unfortunately I am getting this error: `http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response`

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

def LoginGMB(driver):    
    (myemail, mypassword) = AuthenticationDetails()   
    driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys(myemail)
    driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(mypassword)
    driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext').click()
    time.sleep(2)

def OpenGMB(url):    
    driver.get(url)
    print(driver.current_url)
    pattern = re.compile(".*accounts.google.com/signin.*")
    match = re.search(pattern, cururl)
    if match:
        LoginGMB(driver)
    print("Ok we're back")
    driver.find_element_by_id('ow50').click()

OpenGMB('https://business.google.com/edit/l/001?hl=en')
```

Stacktrace:

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=lbc&passive=1209600&continue
We need to login as we are presented login page
Ok we're back
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gmb.py", line 77, in <module>
    OpenGMB(url)
File "gmb.py", line 62, in OpenGMB
    el = driver.find_element_by_id('ow50')
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 376, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 399, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 72, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 150, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 323, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These error messages...

```
    RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

and

```
    RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

...implies that the **Remote Connection** was disconnected due to **ProtocolError**.

As per [urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799251/urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-aborted-error10054-an-exist) This issue is pretty evident when there is a **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

As you are using **ChromeDriver** and **Chrome Browser** you must ensure that the binaries are compatible as per the entries below:

- ChromeDriver v2.46: Supports Chrome v71-73
- ChromeDriver v2.45: Supports Chrome v70-72
- ChromeDriver v2.44: Supports Chrome v69-71 (same as ChromeDriver 2.43, but with additional bug fixes)
- ChromeDriver v2.43: Supports Chrome v69-71
- ChromeDriver v2.42: Supports Chrome v68-70
- ChromeDriver v2.41: Supports Chrome v67-69
- ChromeDriver v2.40: Supports Chrome v66-68
- ChromeDriver v2.39: Supports Chrome v66-68
- ChromeDriver v2.38: Supports Chrome v65-67
- ChromeDriver v2.37: Supports Chrome v64-66
- ChromeDriver v2.36: Supports Chrome v63-65
- ChromeDriver v2.35: Supports Chrome v62-64
- ChromeDriver v2.34: Supports Chrome v61-63
- ChromeDriver v2.33: Supports Chrome v60-62
- ChromeDriver v2.32: Supports Chrome v59-61
- ChromeDriver v2.31: Supports Chrome v58-60
- ChromeDriver v2.30: Supports Chrome v58-60
- ChromeDriver v2.29: Supports Chrome v56-58
- ChromeDriver v2.28: Supports Chrome v55-57
- ChromeDriver v2.27: Supports Chrome v54-56

> **Note**: A few months ago, *Chromium Team* made a [preliminary announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/HvlKWqv34es) that ChromeDriver's versioning model will be changing. Now we are moving forward with the plan. Specifically, ChromeDriver 2.46 will be the last release carrying the major version of 2. Future ChromeDriver releases will carry a version number similar to Chrome release. We will start with a release of ChromeDriver 73 next week, before the Beta release of Chrome 73.

Here is how the new release model will work:

- ChromeDriver will be using the same version number scheme as Chrome. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/version-numbers for more details.
- Each version of ChromeDriver will support Chrome with matching major, minor, and build version numbers. For example, upcoming ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.* will support all Chrome versions that start with 73.0.3683.
- Before a new major version of Chrome goes to Beta, a matching version of ChromeDriver will be released. For example, a new version of ChromeDriver will be release next week to match the Beta release of Chrome m73.
- After the initial release of a new major version, we will release patches as needed. These patches may or may not coincide with updates to Chrome.

Comment: What if you're using PhantomJS? What could the problem be related to