# WebDriverException: Message: Service /content/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6 with ChromeDriver Google Colab and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

I was trying to run headless Chrome browser using Selenium to scrape contents from the web. I installed headless Chrome using wget and then unzipped in my current folder.

```
!wget "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
!unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

Now when I am loading the driver

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
# instantiate a chrome options object so you can set the size and headless preference
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

chrome_driver = os.getcwd() +"/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path=chrome_driver)
```

I am getting an error

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-0aeae0cfd891> in <module>()
----> 1 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
  2 driver.get("https://www.google.com")
  3 lucky_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name=btnI]")
  4 lucky_button.click()
  5 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, chrome_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path)
 60             service_args=service_args,
 61             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 62         self.service.start()
 63 
 64         try:

 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
 84         count = 0
 85         while True:
 ---> 86             self.assert_process_still_running()
 87             if self.is_connectable():
 88                 break

 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in assert_process_still_running(self)
 97             raise WebDriverException(
 98                 'Service %s unexpectedly exited. Status code was: %s'
 ---> 99                 % (self.path, return_code)
100             )
101 

WebDriverException: Message: Service /content/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

### Update

So after some research I tried the other way

```
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
import selenium as se

options = se.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = se.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

On Google Colab which again gives me the same error

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

Comment: @DebanjanB The 3 questions don't have a relevant answer to this question. The OS is different (Win vs. Linux) and no accepted answers.

Comment: None of the answer is related to error code -6. I tried all the methods. Please do not mark duplicate before reading the entire question.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich The main error is **chromedriver unexpectedly exited**. Different _OS_ and different _Selenium Language Binding Arts_ will show different `Status code` for the same error. I have pointed OP to the most relevant discussions. Let me know if you have further concerns.

Comment: Yes I do none of the solution you guyz pointed resolve my issue

Comment: i think the intent here is to scrape web why are you not using beautifulsoup  instead

Comment: Beautiful soup cannot scrape javascript generated content

Comment: Please share a notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found the answer to the question about why I was getting an error. Please install the chromium-chromedriver and add it to your path variable as well as the bin directory.

This is the fully-fledged solution to the problem of how to scrape data using Selenium on Colab. There is one more method by using PhantomJS but this API has been deprecated by Selenium and hopefully they will remove it in the next Selenium update.

```
# install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get("https://www.website.com")
print(wd.page_source)  # results
```

This would work for anyone who want to scrape their data on Google Colab and not on your local machine.  Please execute the steps as shown sequentially in the same order.

You can find the notebook here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GFJKhpOju_WLAgiVPCzCGTBVGMkyAjtk .

Comment: From the warning "DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options". Is there a reason to use chrome_options instead of options?

Comment: Also, I don't think sys.path.insert() is necessary. sys.path is for searching python modules, not executables.

Comment: No sys.path.insert() is not necessary you can remove it.  I have edited my answer. And for options I could not find its new release analogous function.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich I was think there is a problem in this statement webdriver.ChromeOptions() but the real cause was somewhere else. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184633/discussion-between-himanshu-poddar-and-korakot-chaovavanich).

Comment: Can you also explain about --disable-dev-shm-usage and --no-sandbox. Just curious. Is there information why it is needed somewhere?

Comment: this work me last time but this time i try again on my server it get following exceptions:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 104, in start                
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)                                           
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service chromedriver  
Can you help please, im banned from questioning on statckoverflow

Comment: Works fine for me still!

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /content/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** exited unexpectedly.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- As per the line of code:

  ```
  !wget "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
  ```
- You are using *chromedriver=2.25*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.25*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v53-55**

- Though you haven't mentioned the version of *Chrome Browser* it is expected you are using one of the latest *Chrome Browser* releases.

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.33* and the recently released *Chrome Browser* versions.

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.44**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v69-71*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.44 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt))

---

### Update

I am not sure about `google-colaboratory`. The bottomline is you have to use the matching version of *ChromeDriver* with respect to the prevailing version of *Google Chrome* version installed.

However, you need to find a way to install Chrome or Chromium on Colab first. Then, you can use **`!wget`** and **`!unzip`** to **download**, **unzip** and start using the matching *ChromeDriver* version.

You can find a discussion on the compatibility between *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375824/remotedisconnectedremote-end-closed-connection-without-http-client-remotedisc/53388111#53388111)

Comment: I am doing this on colab. Why do I need to install google chrome on cloud.

Comment: @DebanjanB Please provide a relevant answer to 'Google Colaboratory'. It's a free Jupyter Notebook service running ubuntu 17 at https://colab.research.google.com

There is no 'Project Workspace', no IDE, no Rebuild, no Revo. You can't reboot it like your laptop.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I am not sure about `google-colaboratory`. The bottomline is  you have to use the relevant _ChromeDriver_ as per the version of the prevailing _Google Chrome_ version.

Comment: In Colab, you can only install things through `!apt` or `!apt-get` or `!wget` or `!pip install`. You can't interact with the command line, so need to use -y options.

Comment: The hard things are: 1. How to install Chrome through command line? 2. How to check that Chrome is installed correctly? 3. How to check if ChromeDriver work correctly with Chrome? The rest is easy: !pip install selenium, then test it.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich You don't even need to install Chrome, just use the one whichever is installed. You can always use `!wget` and `!unzip` to download and start using the matching _ChromeDriver_.

Comment: @DebanjanB There is no browser installed already in Colab. You only have wget and curl. You need to install either Chrome or Chromium or even Firefox. But I am not sure how to install them.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich You will need a browser installed either among Chrome or Chromium or even Firefox to execute any test through Selenium.

Comment: @DebanjanB That's right. The key issue here is how to install a browser. I gave one example below installing phantomjs. Please make one for Chrome, if you can.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich but the problem with phantomjs is they are gonna remove the support for phantomjs in selenium's next version.

Comment: @DebanjanB Please edit your answer about Chrome installation. *Test Environment* is Colab. And it doesn't come with Chrome installed.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich **`WebDriverException`** is a _Selenium_ specific exception and is pretty generic irrespective of _Chrome_, _Chrome Canary_ and _google-colaboratory_ where the main reason is plain mismatch of the _binary versions_. Now, whether _google-colaboratory_ allows _Chrome_ browser upgrade or not will be a separate question/discussion all together and would be best answered by _google-colaboratory_ contributors. However as the end result is _WebDriverException_ for the benefit of the future readers IMO we need to keep this information.

Comment: @DebanjanB What you said here "just use the existing installation of Google Chrome whichever is installed in your Test Environment." is simply wrong. Please correct it. The rest is useful, thanks!

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich As the question is tagged with _google-colaboratory_ and you being a valued contributor to _google-colaboratory_ tag, you are always welcome to make the minor adjustments to make this/any content useful to future readers.

Comment: @DebanjanB Ok, corrected them. I can't install Chrome/Chromium myself so a bit embarrassed at this, though. Hope someone who succeeds can make an example Colab notebook for us.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich Thanks for the useful edit. If _install Chrome or Chromium on Colab first_ is the only way out, I think I have a better solution to offer. However that would be _out of scope_ for this question and you have to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich While you raise the question please be precise that you want to execute _Selenium_ related tests on _google-colaboratory_ which doesn't have _Chrome_ pre-installed. Ask about the best ideas/options. I think community will accept the question happily.

Comment: @DebanjanB Please answer it here. So anyone searching can find the answer easily. I start a bounty as a thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

This may not directly help you. But if eventually, you can't install Chrome + selenium, you can still use phantomjs + selenium. Like this notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1V62zhjw2V5buxdN1s9mqkLzh3FWqSq8S

But I would prefer Chrome, if possible.