# Selenium in Google Colab without having to worry about managing the ChromeDriver executable - i tried an example using kora.selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

**Selenium in Google Colab without having to worry about managing the ChromeDriver executable - i tried  an example using kora.selenium**

after serveral hard times with selenium and google-colab i tried to get a easier way  to  user selenium no cloab! See

The kora library provides a convenient way to use Selenium in Google Colab without having to worry about managing the ChromeDriver executable. today i tried out the an example using kora.selenium:

see my **approach:**

```
from kora.selenium import wd  # web driver
print(wd.session_id)  # 8be87366df11b09b552fb4ad7efbd696

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69144967/is-running-selenium-on-google-colab-possible


!pip install kora

from kora.selenium import wd

# Example: Open Google and search for a term
search_term = "Hello, Google Colab!"
wd.get("https://www.google.com/")
search_box = wd.find_element("name", "q")
search_box.send_keys(search_term)
search_box.submit()

# Wait for a few seconds to let the results load
wd.implicitly_wait(5)

# Print the title of the page
print("Page title:", wd.title)

# Close the browser window
wd.quit()
```

well - the  kora.selenium, the WebDriver (wd) is automatically set up for colab, and we don't need to worry about the chrome_driver_path or any other configuration. This simplifies the process of using Selenium in a Colab environment.

but **wait**: see what i i get back!?

this  is annoying:

```
Collecting kora
  Downloading kora-0.9.20-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 57.7/57.7 kB 1.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from kora) (7.34.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fastcore in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from kora) (1.5.29)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from fastcore->kora) (23.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from fastcore->kora) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (67.7.2)
Collecting jedi>=0.16 (from ipython->kora)
  Downloading jedi-0.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.6/1.6 MB 9.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (5.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (3.0.43)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (2.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-inline in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (0.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ipython->kora) (4.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython->kora) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pexpect>4.3->ipython->kora) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython->kora) (0.2.13)
Installing collected packages: jedi, kora
Successfully installed jedi-0.19.1 kora-0.9.20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-495f2524b7a6> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install kora')
      2 
----> 3 from kora.selenium import wd
      4 
      5 # Example: Open Google and search for a term

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kora/selenium.py in <module>
     11 options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
     12 # create a webdriver instance, ready to use
---> 13 wd = Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
     14 
     15 # make it easier to query and explore elements

TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

see the colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15BgMqgfkzo4a3ocX3ORpjGXUoVVxN56o?usp=sharing

any ideas here - how to get the  tiny example up and runing!?

**btw**: this approach does not run as well - on **google-colab:**

```
!pip install selenium
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://clutch.co/il/it-services"
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Your scraping logic goes here
company_info = soup.select(".directory-list div.provider-info")

data_list = []
for info in company_info:
    company_name = info.select_one(".company_info a").get_text(strip=True)
    location = info.select_one(".locality").get_text(strip=True)
    website = info.select_one(".company_info a")["href"]

    # Additional information you want to extract goes here
    # For example, you can extract the description
    # description = info.select_one(".description").get_text(strip=True)

    description = [i for i in info.find_all("div") if 'description' in ''.join(i['class'])][0].get_text(strip=True)


    data_list.append({
        "Company Name": company_name,
        "Location": location,
        "Website": website,
        "Description": description
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df.index += 1

print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql"))
df.to_csv("it_services_data_enriched.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

it **gives** back **the following:**

```
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-131b400baa45> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 options = Options()
      9 options.headless = True
---> 10 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
     11 
     12 url = "https://clutch.co/il/it-services"

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    227                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    228             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/121.0.6167.85/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5845acb92d93 <unknown>
#1 0x5845ac876337 <unknown>
#2 0x5845ac8aabc0 <unknown>
#3 0x5845ac8a6765 <unknown>
#4 0x5845ac8f0b7c <unknown>
#5 0x5845ac8e41e3 <unknown>
#6 0x5845ac8b4135 <unknown>
#7 0x5845ac8b513e <unknown>
#8 0x5845acb56e4b <unknown>
#9 0x5845acb5adfa <unknown>
#10 0x5845acb436d5 <unknown>
#11 0x5845acb5ba6f <unknown>
```

i am encountering some bad things: guess that there's an issue starting the Chrome browser via Selenium. Well - i guess that this could be due to various reasons, such as incompatible versions of ChromeDriver and Chrome browser, or missing dependencies.

i need to make up my mind how to troubleshoot and fix this issue:
i could try Try Headless Mode, or different browsers well - we need to have some more light into these things....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [Google-Colab-Selenium](https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium) to solve this problem. It manages the executable and the required Selenium Options for you.

Comment: Dear Jakob, that sounds very intereesting - well having a solution that makes such kind of jobs running on google colab would be very awesome and outstannding - i am curiouls to get more insights. having tried to run selenium jobs on colab  several times i woud love to digg deeper in your ideas and solutions.

Comment: hello dear Jakob - this is very interesting! i have worked on such a solution for  quiet a long long time.  I am currently ironing out to get a scraper to work that needs to be able to run on Google-Colab. It would be terrific if your solution would work on the colab. See my approach here on the  Thread - where i am working . see the scraper that i have to get data from clutch.co : being a big colab-fan i would be more than happy if i get this running on colab.  see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888886/running-bs4-scraper-needs-to-be-redefined-to-enrich-the-dataset-some-issues

Comment: @thannen The package should work with any Selenium code! Essentially you just need to copy and paste the code into a Colab notebook and then change the WebDriver instance to the Google-Colab-Selenium instance. I have a few examples in the GitHub README.md

Comment: many thanks - your example and the provided colab  is very instructive - and clear. Awesome. BTW; good evening

many thanks - your so great  and this is a awesome place to be
run this tiny parser that works well  - but at a certain point it lacks some precision
see below:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F3cDTaumFyXj1o3k_i-1mOzIOZBn8KsH?usp=sharing
well  at the moment i wonder why the xpath on the "Website" does not give back some more results.guess that i have to do a better defining of this tiny part of the script - and to write a propper path  towards this entity!?Any idea

Answer (score 0):

thanks to you Jakob and your outstanding idea that you share
with your  Google-Colab-Selenium-approach - to solve this problem. ( https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium ) we were able to manages the challenge - due to the great concept of your project (that comes with all the required Selenium Options)
this script runs very well - even on **google-Colab:**

```
%pip install -q curl_cffi
%pip install -q fake-useragent
%pip install -q lxml

from curl_cffi import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from lxml.html import fromstring
from IPython.display import HTML
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

ua = UserAgent()
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.safari}

base_url = 'https://clutch.co/es/it-services'
page_number = 1
data = []

while True:
    resp = requests.get(f'{base_url}?page={page_number}', headers=headers, impersonate="safari15_3")
    tree = fromstring(resp.text)
    companies = tree.xpath('//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "provider")]')

    if not companies:
        break

    for company in companies:
        contact_phone = company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-phone"]//span/text()')
        phone = contact_phone[0].strip() if contact_phone else 'Not Available'

        contact_email = company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-email"]//a/text()')
        email = contact_email[0].strip() if contact_email else 'Not Available'

        contact_address = company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-address"]//span/text()')
        address = contact_address[0].strip() if contact_address else 'Not Available'

        data.append({
            "name": company.xpath('./@data-title')[0].strip(),
            "location": company.xpath('.//span[@class = "locality"]')[0].text,
            "wage": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Avg. hourly rate</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
            "min_project_size": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Min. project size</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
            "employees": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Employees</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
            "description": company.xpath('.//blockquote//p')[0].text,
            "website_link": (company.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "website-link__item")]/@href') or ['Not Available'])[0],
            # Additional fields
            "services_offered": [service.text.strip() for service in company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Services</i>"]/span/a')],
            "client_reviews": [review.text.strip() for review in company.xpath('.//div[@class="rating__number"]/text()')],
            "contact_information": {
                "phone": phone,
                "email": email,
                "address": address
            }
            # Add more fields as needed
        })

    page_number += 1

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = json_normalize(data, max_level=0)

df.head()
```

**output:**

```
+----------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|      name      |         location          |       wage       | min_project_size |  employees  |                    description                    |                   website_link                    | services_offered | client_reviews |                contact_information                |                                                   |
+----------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| SCL Consulting | Pozuelo de Alarcón, Spain | Undisclosed      | Undisclosed      | 250 - 999   | SCL Consulting is an international consulting ... | Not Available                                     | []               | []             | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |                                                   |
| 1              | Cartagon                  | Madrid, Spain    | Undisclosed      | Undisclosed | 10 - 49                                           | Cartagon is the leading provider of Managed Cl... | Not Available    | []             | []                                                | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |
| 2              | Zucchetti                 | Madrid, Spain    | Undisclosed      | Undisclosed | 250 - 999                                         | We are Zucchetti Spain, the division of the Zu... | Not Available    | []             | []                                                | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |
| 3              | NTT DATA                  | Barcelona, Spain | Undisclosed      | Undisclosed | 10,000+                                           | NTT DATA – a part of NTT Group - is a top 10 g... | Not Available    | []             | []                                                | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |
| 4              | Sermicro                  | Madrid, Spain    | Undisclosed      | Undisclosed | 1,000 - 9,999                                     | Sermicro Group is an ICT Solutions and Service... | Not Available    | []             | []                                                | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |
+----------------+---------------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

many thanks dear Jacob - i have been searching quite some weeks to find any solution  - and you provided this.  You are a true hero!!!

have a great day ;)