# running bs4 scraper needs to be redefined to enrich the dataset - some issues

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

got a bs4  scraper that works with selenium  - see far below:

well - it works fine so far:

see far below my approach to fetch some data form **the given page**: clutch.co/il/it-services

To enrich the scraped data, with additional information, i tried to modify the scraping-logic to extract more details from each company's page. Here's i have to an updated version of the code that extracts the company's website and additional information:

here we have **script1**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://clutch.co/il/it-services"
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Your scraping logic goes here
company_info = soup.select(".directory-list div.provider-info")

data_list = []
for info in company_info:
    company_name = info.select_one(".company_info a").get_text(strip=True)
    location = info.select_one(".locality").get_text(strip=True)
    website = info.select_one(".company_info a")["href"]
    
    # Additional information you want to extract goes here
    # For example, you can extract the description
    description = info.select_one(".description").get_text(strip=True)
    
    data_list.append({
        "Company Name": company_name,
        "Location": location,
        "Website": website,
        "Description": description
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df.index += 1

print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql"))
df.to_csv("it_services_data_enriched.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

**ideas to this** extended version: well in this code, I added a loop to go through **each company's information**, extracted the website, and added a placeholder for additional information (in this case, the description). i thougth that i can adapt this loop to extract more data as needed. At least this  is the idea.

the **working model:**  i think that the structure of the HTML of course changes here -  and therefore in need  to adapt the scraping-logik: so i think that i might need to adjust the CSS selectors accordingly based on the current structure of the page. So far so good: Well,i think that we need to make sure to customize the scraping logic based on the specific details we want to extract from each company's page. Conclusio: well i think i am very close: but  see what i  gotten back: the following

```
/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/clutch_scraper_2/.venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/clutch_scraper_2/clutch_scraper_II.py
/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/clutch_scraper_2/clutch_scraper_II.py:2: DeprecationWarning:
Pyarrow will become a required dependency of pandas in the next major release of pandas (pandas 3.0),
(to allow more performant data types, such as the Arrow string type, and better interoperability with other libraries)
but was not found to be installed on your system.
If this would cause problems for you,
please provide us feedback at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54466
       
 import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/clutch_scraper_2/clutch_scraper_II.py", line 29, in <module>
   description = info.select_one(".description").get_text(strip=True)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Process finished with exit code
```

and now - see below **my allready working model:**  my approach to fetch some data form the given page: clutch.co/il/it-services

here we have **script2**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://clutch.co/il/it-services"
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Your scraping logic goes here
company_names = soup.select(".directory-list div.provider-info--header .company_info a")
locations = soup.select(".locality")

company_names_list = [name.get_text(strip=True) for name in company_names]
locations_list = [location.get_text(strip=True) for location in locations]

data = {"Company Name": company_names_list, "Location": locations_list}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index += 1
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql"))
df.to_csv("it_services_data.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

import pandas as pd

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|    | Company Name                                        | Location                       |
|----+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------|
|  1 | Artelogic                                           | L'viv, Ukraine                 |
|  2 | Iron Forge Development                              | Palm Beach Gardens, FL         |
|  3 | Lionwood.software                                   | L'viv, Ukraine                 |
|  4 | Greelow                                             | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
|  5 | Ester Digital                                       | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
|  6 | Nextly                                              | Vitória, Brazil                |
|  7 | Rootstack                                           | Austin, TX                     |
|  8 | Novo                                                | Dallas, TX                     |
|  9 | Scalo                                               | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 10 | TLVTech                                             | Herzliya, Israel               |
| 11 | Dofinity                                            | Bnei Brak, Israel              |
| 12 | PURPLE                                              | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 13 | Insitu S2 Tikshuv LTD                               | Haifa, Israel                  |
| 14 | Opinov8 Technology Services                         | London, United Kingdom         |
| 15 | Sogo Services                                       | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 16 | Naviteq LTD                                         | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 17 | BMT - Business Marketing Tools                      | Ra'anana, Israel               |
| 18 | Profisea                                            | Hod Hasharon, Israel           |
| 19 | MeteorOps                                           | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 20 | Trivium Solutions                                   | Herzliya, Israel               |
| 21 | Dynomind.tech                                       | Jerusalem, Israel              |
| 22 | Madeira Data Solutions                              | Kefar Sava, Israel             |
| 23 | Titanium Blockchain                                 | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 24 | Octopus Computer Solutions                          | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 25 | Reblaze                                             | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 26 | ELPC Networks Ltd                                   | Rosh Haayin, Israel            |
| 27 | Taldor                                              | Holon, Israel                  |
| 28 | Clarity                                             | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 29 | Opsfleet                                            | Kfar Bin Nun, Israel           |
| 30 | Hozek Technologies Ltd.                             | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 31 | ERG Solutions                                       | Ramat Gan, Israel              |
| 32 | Komodo Consulting                                   | Ra'anana, Israel               |
| 33 | SCADAfence                                          | Ramat Gan, Israel              |
| 34 | Ness Technologies | נס טכנולוגיות                         | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 35 | Bynet Data Communications Bynet Data Communications | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 36 | Radware                                             | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 37 | BigData Boutique                                    | Rishon LeTsiyon, Israel        |
| 38 | NetNUt                                              | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 39 | Asperii                                             | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 40 | PractiProject                                       | Ramat Gan, Israel              |
| 41 | K8Support                                           | Bnei Brak, Israel              |
| 42 | Odix                                                | Rosh Haayin, Israel            |
| 43 | Panaya                                              | Hod Hasharon, Israel           |
| 44 | MazeBolt Technologies                               | Giv'atayim, Israel             |
| 45 | Porat                                               | Tel Aviv-Jaffa, Israel         |
| 46 | MindU                                               | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 47 | Valinor Ltd.                                        | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 48 | entrypoint                                          | Modi'in-Maccabim-Re'ut, Israel |
| 49 | Adelante                                            | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 50 | Code n' Roll                                        | Haifa, Israel                  |
| 51 | Linnovate                                           | Bnei Brak, Israel              |
| 52 | Viceman Agency                                      | Tel Aviv-Jaffa, Israel         |
| 53 | develeap                                            | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 54 | Chalir.com                                          | Binyamina-Giv'at Ada, Israel   |
| 55 | WolfCode                                            | Rishon LeTsiyon, Israel        |
| 56 | Penguin Strategies                                  | Ra'anana, Israel               |
| 57 | ANG Solutions                                       | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

what is aimed: i want to to fetch some more data form the given page: clutch.co/il/it-services - eg the website and so on...

**update_:** The error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' indicates that the .select_one(".description") method did not find any HTML element with the class ".description" for the current company information, resulting in None. Therefore, calling .get_text(strip=True) on None raises an AttributeError.

more to follow... later the day.

**update2:**
note: @jakob had a interesting idea - posted here: [Selenium in Google Colab without having to worry about managing the ChromeDriver executable - i tried an example using kora.selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861365/selenium-in-google-colab-without-having-to-worry-about-managing-the-chromedriver)
I made [Google-Colab-Selenium](https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium) to solve this problem. It manages the executable and the required Selenium Options for you. - well that sounds very very interesting - at the moment i cannot imagine that we get selenium working on colab in such a way - that the above mentioned scraper works on colab full and well!? - ideas !? would be awesome:

**Jakob:** the real issue is that the website you are trying to scrape is using CloudFlare, which can detect selenium.
I wrote a little code to scrape the data that you were looking for.
You actually don't need to use Selenium as the data is already baked right into the HTML when you go to the webpage.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qkZ1OV_Nqeg13UY3S9pY0IXuB4-q3Mvx?usp=sharing

here we have **script3**

```
%pip install -q curl_cffi
%pip install -q fake-useragent
%pip install -q lxml

from curl_cffi import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
# we need to take care for this: https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/

ua = UserAgent()    
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.safari}
resp = requests.get('https://clutch.co/il/it-services', headers=headers, impersonate="safari15_3")
resp.status_code


# I like to use this to verify the contents of the request
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML(resp.text)

from lxml.html import fromstring

tree = fromstring(resp.text)

data = []

for company in tree.xpath('//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "provider")]'):
    data.append({
        "name": company.xpath('./@data-title')[0].strip(),
        "location": company.xpath('.//span[@class = "locality"]')[0].text,
        "wage": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Avg. hourly rate</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "min_project_size": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Min. project size</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "employees": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Employees</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "description": company.xpath('.//blockquote//p')[0].text,
        "website_link": (company.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "website-link__item")]/@href') or ['Not Available'])[0],
    })


import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(data, max_level=0)
df
```

that said - well i think that i understand the approach -  fetching the HTML and then working with xpath the thing i have  difficulties is the user-agent .. part

it works awesome - it is just overwhelming...!!!

Comment: well i think having the .select_one(".description") method not finding  any HTML element with the class ".description" for a given current company information, resulting in None. You have to do more studying of the source code of your target - Well - i think you should check there; To handle this situation, you should check if the element exists before attempting to get its text. You can use an if  statement to verify if the element is found, like this: - just be aware of this detail.,

Comment: note: @jakob had a interesting idea - posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861365/selenium-in-google-colab-without-having-to-worry-about-managing-the-chromedriver
I made [Google-Colab-Selenium](https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium) to solve this problem. It manages the executable and the required Selenium Options for you. - well that sounds very very interesting - at the moment i cannot imagine that we get selenium working on colab in such a way - that the above mentioned scraper works on colab full and well!? - ideas !? would be awesome - ill test it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well to gather more data from the target page like this https://clutch.co/il/it-services there are several methods available  and thinkable. As @Tim Wolfe mentioned above or @eternal_white  - interesting food for thoughts - i personally like the xpath-approach.

but first of all: i have to  say that this  is very interesting: its just a nice and  appropiate way to use Selenium in Google Colab Notebooks
https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium
this is awesome and very nice!

well to gather more data from the target page https://clutch.co/il/it-services, you can consider extracting additional information about each company. Here are some suggestions:

i think you can have a look at serveral parts of the site lemme say e.g. for

**a.** Services Offered: here you can extract for example the list of services each company provides. well, this  piece of information can give you some more insight into their expertise and specialization.

besides  this  we can have a closer look on other data parts  too: for example the

**b.** Client Reviews/Ratings: sometimes i guess this is not available - but if available, we can  scrape client reviews or ratings for each company of
those  israel-based companies: These  kind of data an help to evaluate the reputation and quality of services provided by each of the provided company.

but there is **even more**:  well you can go for...

**c.** Contact Information: you were able  to gather some contact details such as phone numbers, email addresses, or besides  this,
office addresses for each of  the israeli company. These kind of information can be useful for reaching out to potential service providers you find on  the list.

furthermore there is even more: eg. the
**d.** Company Size: Extract the size of each company, such as the number of employees or annual revenue.
well this kind of data can help assess the scale and capacity of the company to handle projects.

last but not least i saw also the

**e.** Portfolio/Projects: If available, (it  is not - as  i saw at a first glance) scrape information about the company's past projects or portfolio. With that kind of data you can get insights into their past work and areas of expertise.

well i would do like so: see the **enhanced data-logic**

```
for company in tree.xpath('//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "provider")]'):
    data.append({
        "name": company.xpath('./@data-title')[0].strip(),
        "location": company.xpath('.//span[@class = "locality"]')[0].text,
        "wage": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Avg. hourly rate</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "min_project_size": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Min. project size</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "employees": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Employees</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "description": company.xpath('.//blockquote//p')[0].text,
        "website_link": (company.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "website-link__item")]/@href') or ['Not Available'])[0],
        # here you can add some more fields as needed
        "services_offered": [service.text.strip() for service in company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Services</i>"]/span/a')],
        "client_reviews": [review.text.strip() for review in company.xpath('.//div[@class="rating__number"]/text()')],
        "contact_information": {
            "phone": company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-phone"]//span/text()')[0].strip(),
            "email": company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-email"]//a/text()')[0].strip(),
            "address": company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-address"]//span/text()')[0].strip()
        }
        # and here too - you can just  add more fields as needed
    })
```

with that the scraper tries to gather data about the services offered by each company, client reviews/ratings, and contact information. and there are further options to customize it to extract additional fields based on any further requirements.

and this would look like so:

```
%pip install -q curl_cffi
%pip install -q fake-useragent
%pip install -q lxml

from curl_cffi import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from lxml.html import fromstring
from IPython.display import HTML
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

ua = UserAgent()    
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.safari}
resp = requests.get('https://clutch.co/il/it-services', headers=headers, impersonate="safari15_3")

tree = fromstring(resp.text)

data = []

for company in tree.xpath('//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "provider")]'):
    contact_phone = company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-phone"]//span/text()')
    phone = contact_phone[0].strip() if contact_phone else 'Not Available'

    contact_email = company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-email"]//a/text()')
    email = contact_email[0].strip() if contact_email else 'Not Available'

    contact_address = company.xpath('.//div[@class="contact-address"]//span/text()')
    address = contact_address[0].strip() if contact_address else 'Not Available'

    data.append({
        "name": company.xpath('./@data-title')[0].strip(),
        "location": company.xpath('.//span[@class = "locality"]')[0].text,
        "wage": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Avg. hourly rate</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "min_project_size": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Min. project size</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "employees": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Employees</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "description": company.xpath('.//blockquote//p')[0].text,
        "website_link": (company.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "website-link__item")]/@href') or ['Not Available'])[0],
        # Additional fields
        "services_offered": [service.text.strip() for service in company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Services</i>"]/span/a')],
        "client_reviews": [review.text.strip() for review in company.xpath('.//div[@class="rating__number"]/text()')],
        "contact_information": {
            "phone": phone,
            "email": email,
            "address": address
        }
        # Add more fields as needed
    })

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = json_normalize(data, max_level=0)

df.head()
```

... should give you back the following dataset

```
+---+---------------+------------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----+----+---------------------------------------------------+
| 0 |  LoovaCloud   |     Haifa, Israel      | $50 - $99 / hr | $25,000+ |  10 - 49  | "This company was highly involved in our proce... |               https://loova.cloud/                | [] | [] | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |
+---+---------------+------------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----+----+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | SEROKELL      | Tel Aviv-Jaffa, Israel | $50 - $99 / hr | $10,000+ | 50 - 249  | "Most importantly, the developed solution cons... | http://serokell.io/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_m... | [] | [] | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |
| 2 | Greelow       | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel  | $25 - $49 / hr | $25,000+ | 10 - 49   | "We were impressed with their sense of ownersh... | https://greelow.com/clutch/?utm_source=clutch.... | [] | [] | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |
| 3 | Ester Digital | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel  | $50 - $99 / hr | $5,000+  | 10 - 49   | "Their visual design skills are top-tier. They... | https://ester.co?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medi... | [] | [] | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |
| 4 | Scalo         | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel  | $50 - $99 / hr | $10,000+ | 250 - 999 | “They are a reliable partner who understands o... | https://www.scalosoft.com/?utm_source=clutch.c... | [] | [] | {'phone': 'Not Available', 'email': 'Not Avail... |
+---+---------------+------------------------+----------------+----------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----+----+---------------------------------------------------+
```

perhaps  some other guys can enhance this a  bit more .... there some place for more... i guess...

**update:** on a sidenote;

btw: the code does not explicitly limit the number of records returned. it allways depents on how the targetpage (your clutchpage) is structured or how the data is being extracted. To ensure that we capture all the relevant data, we can try the following:

**Pagination**: If the page has pagination (multiple pages of results), we might need to modify the code to iterate through all pages and collect data from each page.

Inspect **HTML Structure**: Inspect the HTML structure of the page to ensure that the XPath expressions used to extract data are targeting the correct elements. Sometimes, changes in the page structure can affect data extraction.

**Debugging**:  sometimes its necesary to add print statements or use a debugger to inspect intermediate results and identify any issues with data extraction.

**Error Handling**: sometimes its necesary to have a closer look and to implement error handling to catch any exceptions that might occur during data extraction and logging them for further analysis.

well that said, we can take all these topics into account: here's a general approach to modify the code to handle pagination:

```
base_url = 'https://clutch.co/il/it-services'
page_number = 1
data = []

while True:
    resp = requests.get(f'{base_url}?page={page_number}', headers=headers, impersonate="safari15_3")
    tree = fromstring(resp.text)
    companies = tree.xpath('//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "provider")]')
    
    if not companies:
        break
    
    for company in companies:
        # Extract data for each company and append it to the data list
    
    page_number += 1

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = json_normalize(data, max_level=0)

df.head()
```

**update2** just anoter idea
if your willing to gather data from a set of countries - you can go like so:

```
%pip install -q curl_cffi
%pip install -q fake-useragent
%pip install -q lxml

from curl_cffi import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from lxml.html import fromstring
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

ua = UserAgent()
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.safari}

# List of URLs to scrape
urls = {
    "Deutschland": "https://clutch.co/de/it-services",
    "Frankreich": "https://clutch.co/fr/it-services",
    "Vereinigtes Königreich": "https://clutch.co/uk/it-services",
    "Vereinigte Staaten": "https://clutch.co/us/it-services"
}

# Function to scrape data from a single URL
def scrape_data(url):
    page_number = 1
    data = []

    while True:
        resp = requests.get(f'{url}?page={page_number}', headers=headers, impersonate="safari15_3")
        tree = fromstring(resp.text)
        companies = tree.xpath('//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "provider")]')

        if not companies:
            break
```

**note:** i would add a sleep-time ...

see here

```
   page_number += 1
        sleep(20)  # Pause for 20 seconds before making the next request

    return data

# Iterate over each URL and scrape data
all_data = []
for country, url in urls.items():
    print(f"Scraping data for {country}")
    country_data = scrape_data(url)
    all_data.extend(country_data)

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = json_normalize(all_data, max_level=0)

df.head()
```

any ideas... !?

Comment: Interesting approach and idea. Well I like the idea of adding some country to the loop. You take these dates from the iso Page with the keys for country.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Change this line:

```py
description = info.select_one(".description").get_text(strip=True)
```

to this:

```py
description = [i for i in info.find_all("div") if 'description' in ''.join(i['class'])][0].get_text(strip=True)
```

This will find the tags that has `description` in their class, regardless it's a single class name or it's a part of a whole class name.

---

### Explanation

I'm not an expert in beautifulsoup, I really encourage not using it if you're already dealing with Selenium (selection with selenium is WAY EASIER if you learn [XPATH](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)). Anyways, only one modification is needed in your code to work:

It's this line:

```py
description = info.select_one(".description").get_text(strip=True)
```

should be like this:

```py
description = [i for i in info.find_all("div") if 'description' in ''.join(i['class'])][0].get_text(strip=True)
```

You original code had this:

```py
info.select_one(".description")
```

This will try to find an element in the `info` element you found. There's always a div that has this class: `col-md-3 provider-info__description`.

COOL! we found the element, but bs4 didn't find it. That's because the `.select_one` and `select` functions will split the classes into a list.

So the class we've seen earlier would look like this:
`['col-md-3', 'provider-info__description']`

If you want to test it yourself, try this code:

```py
for i in company_info[0].find_all("div"):
    print(i['class'])
```

This will print all the classes for all `div` tags it will find. You'll see `['col-md-3', 'provider-info__description']` at the bottom.

I don't know why you're using `.select` and `.select_one`, I usually use `.find` and .`find_all` (it needs the tag name, and you can specify classes and other attributes instead of a css selector).

So you could either replace all `.select` to `.find_all` or you would only replace it in this situation (my solution).

OK, back to the solution. So, let's see the new line of code again:

```py
description = [i for i in info.find_all("div") if 'description' in ''.join(i['class'])][0].get_text(strip=True)
```

This line will look for all the `div` tags that are inside your **info** element. Then, it'll only select the ones that have `description` inside their class.

```py
''.join(i['class'])][0].get_text(strip=True)
```

**NOTE**: if you're confused with the syntax of this part, this is called a  Python comprehension. [See here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

The **join** part will combine all the class names in one string, so we don't need to find `description` as a separate class, but we only wanna know if `description` is there or not.

This solution should almost always work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @thannen Please let me know if anything in my explanation wasn't clear, I can explain everything for you.

Comment: Good day dear Eternal_white: first of all i was offlne several days: now i am back again.  many many thanks for the reply - this is really awesome. At the moment i am traveling on a train - with limited options to test and try all things out - but i am doing so later the day when i am at home. In  the meatime - many many thanks for this in depth going and thourough - help - this rocks.. I am really overwhelmed. ;)

Comment: dear eternal_white.  first of all many many thanks for the hints. 
tried out something and  just addet some data to the text numbers from script1 to script3. Well, at the moment only script2 works well either on Pycharm on my linuxnotebook or on googlecolab. need to find out why this is so see also here where i try to add some space to dis cuss / or  we can solve all things here. 
cf. https://dev.to/digital_hub/running-bs4-scraper-needs-to-be-redefined-to-enrich-the-dataset-some-issues-3iln  / at the moment i donno why i do not get it to work
look forward to hear  from you. regards

Comment: dear eternal_White:...additional infos: script3 works on my noteobook in my editor - and script2 works well even on Google-colab.
look forward to hear form you -regards

Comment: eternal_white - many many thanks for all you do - this is so awesome - you have helped me so much. I appreciate all and every help - as i am currently working on several questions - i have to learn alot - see my other - and the newsest questions.

have a great day

Comment: @lebrochet Hello there, I've added a comment there.

Comment: hi there - many many thanks for the reply and for your help tried to cope with the challenge of cloudflare - by using selenium. AT the moment it fails - but i will continue trying with the selenium approach of jakob padilla. - dear eternal white - many many thanks for all you do - its so awesome to see your help - have a great day