# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geckodriver==0.24.0 (from -r /app/requirements.txt (line 4)) error with Selenium Geckodriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, scrapy, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

There's no problem on my local machine. 
But when I deployed it in cloud server specifically in Scrapinghub 
I need to add geckodriver

How can include geckodriver in my requirement.txt?

here's my working code

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
 from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

 def parse_subpage(self, response):

        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", 
                    "localhost")
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 
                    3128)
        profile.update_preferences()

        capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
        capabilities["marionette"] = True
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities, 
                    firefox_profile=profile)

        driver.get('sample.com')
        driver.quit()
```

my Requirement.txt

```
mysql-connector-python
pytz==2018.9
selenium==3.13.0
geckodriver==0.24.0
```

Error observed:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geckodriver==0.24.0 (from -r /app/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: none)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geckodriver==0.24.0 (from -r /app/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: none)
```

...implies that the there was an error while *GeckoDriver* tried to initiate a browsing session through *Firefox*.

Seems there is no *incompatibility* between **geckodriver==0.24.0** and **selenium==3.13.0** as per the documentation in [Supported platforms](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html#supported-platforms).

Presumably, it looks like an issue with the installation location of *Mozilla Firefox*. Either *Firefox* is not installed within your system or *Firefox* is not installed at the **default** (desired) location.

---

### Solution

You need to have *Firefox* installed at the default location. Incase *Firefox* is installed at a **customized** location you need to pass the **absolute path** of the *firefox binary* as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = True
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=capabilities, executable_path="C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Hi @debanjanB, I cannot use local path since I am deploying it through cloud server specifically in scrapinghub. I have no problem when using the script on my local machine.

Comment: @ChristianRead Well, I saw this question coming just like Google  CoLab scenarios. My point is, to work with Selenium and GeckoDriver you need to have Mozilla Firefox installed for sure.

Comment: Yes will take note of that thank you for helping me. Will try other approach to fix this problem

Comment: @ChristianRead For your reference here is the [Google Colab issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532060/webdriverexception-message-service-content-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited/53537003#53537003) where we discussed similar issue with _ChromeDriver_ / _Chrome_ installation.