# WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225477

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, ride

I'm new to Robot Framewerk and I am using it with RIDE and I followed some tutorials and that went well till today.

Yesterday everything worked fine and I changed nothing after yesterday. Now I am getting this error when I execute my tests in RIDE:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225477
```

I'm trying to test on Chrome. Check screenshot for other versions of selenium etc.

Using:

```
Chrome Versie 83.0.4103.61 (Officiële build) (64-bits)
ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39
```

Environment:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225477
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* unexpectedly exited.

---

### Status code: 3221225477

As per the documentation in [Program exit codes](https://www.febooti.com/products/automation-workshop/online-help/actions/run-dos-cmd-command/exit-codes/) `Status Code 3221225477` implies **Access violation** which indicates that the executed program has terminated abnormally or crashed.

As you are using *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* combination there can be numerous reason for this error. A couple of them are as follows:

- Due to incorrect *ChromeDriver* path.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co/49323161#49323161)

- Due to *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* version mismatch.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [WebDriverException: Message: Service /content/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6 with ChromeDriver Google Colab and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532060/webdriverexception-message-service-content-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited/53537003#53537003)