# how to execute javascript on a website using python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to connect to a website (for example [this](https://www.facebook.com/groups/221618226594414/) facebook group) and execute two functions every 5 minutes:

1. `window.scrollBy(0, 6000)`
2. on 7 top posts:

   ```
   let event = new FocusEvent('focusin', {
      'view': window,
      'bubbles': true,
      'cancelable': true
   });
   post.dispatchEvent(event);
   ```
3. Get the webpage content

Ofcourse the first thing that comes in mind is [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), but the problem is that selenium is very heavy on my pc and I'm running this script on a very old pc that it takes too much time to execute.
I was wondering if I can perform that without the need of automating an actual browser, maybe using a library like `requests` or `websockets` to connect to the website and pass some javascript to it (I was able to perform the third point easily with `requests.get(url).content` but the first 2 is the problem)

Comment: JavaScript is executed by the browser. So...

Comment: You need selenium for this.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 any lighter package alternative? my hardware is so poor

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic

Comment: People are running selenium (headless, of course) on raspberry pi 2/3. I suspect you will be just fine.

Comment: Try to use htmlunit browser with javascript.

Comment: You can run selenium headless on colab

Comment: yup selenium can be run on colab https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532060/webdriverexception-message-service-content-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited/53590694#53590694