# Selenium error chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5

Tags: python-3.x, linux, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the following error when trying to use Selenium to scrape a web page:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/****/public_html/.../Dependencies/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5

**Additional information:**

- I am using Selenium version 3.141.0.
- I am using ChromeDriver version 117.0.5938.92.
- I am using the Chrome browser version 117.0.5938.92.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

I have tried the following:

- Making sure that I am using the latest version of ChromeDriver.
- Making sure that I am using the correct ChromeDriver version for my browser.
  https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
- [WebDriverException: Message: Service /content/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6 with ChromeDriver Google Colab and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532060/webdriverexception-message-service-content-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited) this also did not work .

  ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import (TimeoutException, 
    NoSuchElementException)
  ```

  def driver_setup(website):
  """Set up the web driver with Chrome options."""

  ```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1440,1080")
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.binary_location = "/home/**/public_html/chrome-linux64/chrome"
    install_path = "/home/***/public_html/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=install_path, options=options)

    print("Website loading..") 
    driver.get(website)
    return driver
  ```

However, I am still getting the error.

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot this error?