# Cannot connect to chrome at localhost:xxxx from session not created: Chrome version must be >= 69.0.3497.0 with Robot Framework using Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

When I try to connect to a debuggerAddress via chrome web driver i get below error

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:xxxx from session not created: Chrome version must be >= 69.0.3497.0  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

No issue with chromedriver-Chrome version, Since the same is working fine different create driver code.

Working Driver code:

```
Create Webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=C:/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe
```

Issue Driver code:

```
Create Webdriver    Remote    command_executor=http://localhost:yyyy    desired_capabilities=${chrome_cap}
```

### System Details

- Chrome version: 70
- Chrome Driver Version:2.44
- System: Windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: Chrome Capabilities used:       
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")    
chrome_options.debugger_address = "localhost:xxxx"       
chrome_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME    
chrome_capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:xxxx from session not created: Chrome version must be >= 69.0.3497.0 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90)
```

...implies that the **Chrome version must be >= 69.0**

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using **chromedriver=2.44** which ideally supports *Chrome* versions between version **69.x to 71.x**

---

### Solution

As per best practices:

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  the latest [**ChromeDriver v2.45**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Update *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v70-72*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt))

---

### Update A

As per your comment update if you don't have access to upgrade chrome and you need to work with **Chrome v70** you have to download the matching *ChromeDriver* version as per the details within the discussion [RemoteDisconnected(“Remote end closed connection without” http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375824/remotedisconnectedremote-end-closed-connection-without-http-client-remotedisc/53388111#53388111)

---

### Update B

As per your comment update to use a specific version of *Chrome* binary by mentioning installed path you can following the discussion [Cannot find Chrome binary with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/cannot-find-chrome-binary-with-selenium-in-python-for-older-versions-of-google-c/50140554#50140554)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried with v2.45 and still got the same error. So try to downgrade Chromedriver. WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:xxxx from session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)c

Comment: Did you upgrade _Chrome Browser_ accordingly?

Comment: We don't have access to upgrade chrome. Hence need to work with Chrome V70 :)

Comment: Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Tried all versions from V2.42 - V2.45. Still no luck.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have 2 instances of _Chrome_ installed within your system, the default instance with Chrome version **< 70.x** while manually you access the other instance installed at a customized location with _Chrome_ version **70.x**

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. Is there any way we could direct to use specific version of chrome by mentioning installed path?

Comment: @KarthikK Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.