# How to hide the preliminary "data:," that shows up in the url bar when initiating Google Chrome using ChromeDriver?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(my_website)
```

The above code opens my website but only after loading a tab with the title **`data:,`** for a second or two. How do I hide it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code successfully opens the website properly through [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) after loading a tab with the title **`data:,`** for a second or two, is perfectly fine.

The main concern is, your program shouldn't be stuck with **`data:,`** in the url bar. Incase this situation happens the simplest solution would be to:

- Check if the url is properly formatted. As an example, you have mentioned the protocol along with the actual url as follows:

  ```
  http://localhost:3000
  ```
- You are using compatibile version of binaries in terms of *Google Chrome Browser* and [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)
- [Selenium for ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser and the log message “Only local connections are allowed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547360/selenium-for-chromedriver-and-chrome-browser-and-the-log-message-only-local-con/48551748#48551748)
- [WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited on Raspberry-Pi with ChromeDriver and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796818/webdriverexception-message-service-usr-lib-chromium-browser-chromedriver-unex/49799791#49799791)
- [RemoteDisconnected(“Remote end closed connection without” http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375824/remotedisconnectedremote-end-closed-connection-without-http-client-remotedisc/53388111#53388111)