# How to fix ‘ConnectionResetErrort’ in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, urllib3

My script has been working fine, then all of a sudden it started throwing the following messages:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Some details:

Chrome: 77.0.3865.90
Webdriver: 77.0.3865.40
Selenium: 3.141.0
Python: 3.6.5

I've tried this: 
[urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799251/urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-aborted-error10054-an-exist)

def advanced_search():

```
# some code here

xpath_expand = '//*[@id="navigatorPanel-xcollapsed"]'
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_expand).click() 

# some code here
```